# Every element of $\mathit H$ is representable as a product of $\mathit H$-irreducible elements

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

I have the following exercise to do.

Let $\mathit H := \{4n+1 : n \in \mathbb N_0 \} \subseteq \mathbb N$. An element $p \in H \setminus \{1 \}$ is called $H$-irreducible if the following is true:

- if $p = a \cdot b$  where $a,b \in H$, then either $a = 1$ or $b = 1$.

Proove that every element of $\mathit H$ is representable as a product of $\mathit H$-irreducible elements.

As I understand it, I have to prove that every $q \in H$ can be written as $q = p\cdot r$ where $p,r$ are $H$-irreducible.

Before I start my attempt, a remark. I managed to prove that for $a,b \in H$ that $a \cdot b \in H$.

Let $p = a \cdot b$ and $r = c \cdot d$ with $a,b,c,d \in H$. Then $q = p \cdot r = a \cdot b \cdot c \cdot d$.

1. case: $a = 1, c = 1$. Then $q = b \cdot d$ and $q \in H$.
2. case: $a = 1, d = 1$. Then $q = b \cdot c$ and $q \in H$.
3. case: $b = 1, c = 1$. Then $q = a \cdot d$ and $q \in H$.
4. case: $b = 1, d = 1$. Then $q = a \cdot c$ and $q \in H$.

Is this a valid proof?

Also, if I calculate the first few terms of $H$ then I get:

$H = \{1,5,9,13,17,21,...\}$. How exactly can I get for example $13$ as a product of two elements of $H$ ?

Comment: The problem asks to prove that an element in $H$ is a product of *some* irreducible elements... they can be one, two, three or a finite number of irreducibles, e.g. $13$ is irreducible and is the only one in its representation, $125=5\cdot 5\cdot 5$.

Comment: @Davide One minor thing is that the number of irreducible elements may also be $0$, e.g., for $1 \in \mathit H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Proove that every element of $\mathit H$ is representable as a product of $\mathit H$-irreducible elements.
> As I understand it, I have to prove that every $q \in H$ can be written as $q = p\cdot r$ where $p,r$ are $H$-irreducible.

Your understanding as stated in the second sentence is not quite correct (as also indicated in [Davide](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1008581/davide)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4358565/every-element-of-mathit-h-is-representable-as-a-product-of-mathit-h-irredu/4358603#comment9100794_4358565)). The question is asking to prove that each element of $\mathit H$ can be represented as a product of *any* number (i.e., $0$ or more, so not necessarily exactly $2$) of $\mathit H$-irreducible elements. This is similar to as the statement that all positive integers can be represented as a product of primes means $0$ or more primes (e.g., $1$ is the only positive integer which is a product of $0$ primes).

Consider any element $h \in \mathit H$. It can be represented using some integers $m, n \ge 0$ by

$$h = \left(\prod_{i=1}^{m}p_i\right)\left(\prod_{j=1}^{2n}q_j\right) \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

where $p_i$ are primes congruent to $1$ modulo $4$ and $q_j$ are primes congruent to $3$ modulo $4$. The number of primes of the form $q_j$ must be even because an odd number of them would result in $h \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$.

Since the only factors of $p_i$ (for $1 \le i \le m$) in $\mathit H$ are $1$ and $p_i$, then $p_i = a \times b$ where $a, b \in \mathit H$ means $a$ or $b$ is $1$, i.e., $p_i$ is irreducible.

With $r = q_j q_k$ for any $1 \le j, k \le 2n$, then $r = a \times b$ (with $a$ and $b$ being positive integers) means there are $2$ possibilities. First, $a$ and $b$ are $q_j$ and $q_k$, in some order. However, neither $a$ nor $b$ would then be elements of $\mathit H$. The second possibility is $a$ and $b$ are $1$ and $r$ in some order, so since $1, r \in \mathit{H}$, this shows $r$ is irreducible.

Thus, rewriting \eqref{eq1A} as

$$h = \left(\prod_{i=1}^{m}p_i\right)\left(\prod_{j=1}^{n}(q_{2j-1}q_{2j})\right) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

indicates how $h$ can be written as a product of the $\mathit H$-irreducible elements $p_i$ and $q_{2j-1}q_{2j}$.

Comment: thanks for the answer and for the typo! I fixed it! I got some questions regarding your answer because I don't quite understand the proof.

Comment: 1. I'm assuming that in $(1)$ you use the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, i.e. $h$ can be written as a product of primes. Why is there a split into $p_i$ and $q_j$ ?
2. Why isn't $h$ allowed to be congruent to $3 \bmod 4$

Comment: @syphracos You're welcome for the answer. My $(1)$ is not using the FTA since it's just stating that $h$ is a product of primes, with there being no need at that point for this decomposition to be unique. However, the FTA *is* basically used later with my $r = q_j q_k$ not being able to be rewritten as a product of different primes when checking what values of $a$ and $b$ may have with $r = a \times b$. As for splitting $h$ into $p_i$ and $q_j$ primes, this is because a positive integer is an element of $\mathit H$ iff it's of the form $4n + 1$, i.e., congruent to $1$ mod $4$. (cont.)

Comment: @syphracos Thus, each $p_i$ is a member by itself, but $q_j$ is not, with it requiring to be paired with another $q_k$ since $q_j q_k \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ so it's then a member. This different behavior is why I split the primes in $(1)$ so I can treat each case separately, as shown in the answer. Finally, $h$ is not allowed to be congruent to $3$ mod $4$ since $h \in \mathit H$ so $h$ is of the form $4n + 1$, i.e., $h \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$.

Comment: okay, thanks for the clarification! I will try to go through it and try to understand the proof. If there will be something unclear, I'll ask again. Cheers!

Comment: @syphracos FYI, you may find it easier to first prove the $\mathit H$-irreducible elements are only of the form of $p_i$ or $q_j q_k$ I used in my answer, & then show all $\mathit H$ elements can be represented as a product of them. This is basically the reverse of what I did. I considered answering that way, but thought my way would be better. Nonetheless, I may be mistaken. My experience teaching (actually, mostly tutoring) math showed there's no single method which works for everybody, so I sometimes had to try several ways to find one that worked well for a particular person.

Comment: @syphracos Another thing which may be of interest to you, in case you haven't already noticed, is that if $n \ge 2$, i.e., there are at least $4$ $q_j$ primes, the representation in terms of $\mathit H$-irreducible elements is *not* unique. For example, $h = 3(3)(7)(7)$ is an element of  $\mathit H$ that can be represented by $h = 9(49)$ and $h = 21(21)$, where $9$, $49$ and $21$ are all $\mathit H$-irreducible elements.

Comment: again, thank you very much! It is clearer now and I will mark it as an answer. Cheers!